# How to auto display php function parameter in vim?

Tags: php, vim

How to auto display php function parameter in vim  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using <kbd>c-x c-o</kbd> — that should do it.

For example, if you type `mysql`, then hit <kbd>c-x c-o</kbd>, you'll get a list of the `mysql` functions and a the scratch buffer will show you, for example `mysql_connect([string server [, string username [, string password [, bool new_link [, int client_flags]]]]] | resource`.